# Show that any matrix $A=B' B$ with $B'$ conjugate transpose has real positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on a linear algebra problem that I just cannot wrap my head around.

1) Show that any $n × n$ matrix $A$ of the form $$A = B'B$$ has eigenvalues that are all real and positive. Here, $B$ is
any invertible $n × n$ matrix with real or complex entries, and $B'$
is its conjugate transpose

Now I know, any Hermitian matrix $A$ has real eigenvalues, and any matrix $A$ of form $$A = B' B$$ is Hermitian, thus its eigenvalues are real. But I just cannot find out why they should be positive as well.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\langle x, A x \rangle = \langle x, B' B x \rangle = \langle Bx, Bx \rangle, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb C^n. $$

Comment: This gives rise to $\lambda <x,x> = x'Ax$, right? Am I on the right direction? - edit I feel that this leads to just a trivial result

Comment: @user282639 You didn't use Stefano's hint yet. You can write $x'Ax$ (or $\langle x, Ax\rangle$, which is the same thing) as something else (and **here** you use the hint)

Comment: I think I'm struggling to see the connection here

Comment: @user282639 You already know that $\lambda \langle x, x\rangle = \langle x, Ax\rangle$ (which is what you wrote in your first comment). Now, use the hint which tells you that one of the sides of the equation $\lambda \langle x, x\rangle = \langle x, Ax\rangle$ is also equal to something else... What equation do you get?

Comment: $\lambda <x,x> = <Bx, Bx>$. It's getting super late/early I feel like I'm not seeing something very obvious

Comment: @user282639 **Hint**: one of the properties of an inner product tells you something about the sign of a couple of the terms that appear in your equation.

Comment: I think I arrive at $\lambda= \frac{\Vert Bx \Vert ^2}{\Vert x \Vert ^2}$. I think this should give the desired property. How does the second equality come about?

Comment: @user282639 What "second equality"?

Comment: $\langle x , B'Bx \rangle = \langle Bx , Bx \rangle$. But I figured that $x'B'Bx = (Bx)'Bx = \langle Bx, Bx \rangle$. Does that sound right?

Comment: @user282639 That's one way of seeing it, yes. Another is that if $C$ is a matrix, then **by definition**, $C'$ is defined as the matrix for which $\langle Cx, y\rangle=\langle x, C'y\rangle$ is true for all $x$. So, if you set $y=Bx$, then by definition, $\langle x, B'(Bx)\rangle$ must be equal to $\langle Bx, Bx\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand now